# Constructible polygons

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry

I know certain polygons can be constructed while others cannot. Here is Gauss' Theorem on Constructions:

$\cos(2π/n)$ is constructible iff $n = 2^{r}p_{1}p_{2} · · · p_{k}$, where each $p_i$ is a
Fermat prime.

Can this is be used to determine the constructibility of a regular $p^2$ polygon? If so how and what would be the $\cos(2\pi/n)$ here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $p_i$ have to be *distinct* Fermat primes, so a regular polygon with $p^2$ sides  is constructible only when $p=2$.

Comment: So why cant p > 2 be written this way in terms of Fermat Primes?

Comment: @Debbie Because you didnt write Gauss' theorem completely. $p_k$ isnt JUST a Fermat prime; but they have to be pairwise distinct.  Which means you can only have one of each Fermat prime.